# How to input a list in the parameter of the "Evaluate Spline" node in animation node?

Tags: animation, node-editor, animation-nodes

When I connect the "Evaluate Spline" node and the animation node nothing happens. It stays disconnected.

[image: screenshot of the problem with both nodes besides each other, disconnected]

Comment: Cannot replicate the issue..

Comment: Are you sure you are using the most recent version of Animation Nodes? A lot of vectorization functionality was added in version 2.0.

Comment: This is only available in version 2.1.

Comment: Just for information, if the parameter is not vectorized, you need to input lists in the parameters using a Loop Subprogram.